# Get URL of a website at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, url

Is there any way to get a URL from a website e.g goodreads.com at runtime. Because I am taking book name as input for getting book reviews from goodreads and I also have written a js function to convert book name in the format used by goodreads(like this:The_Da_Vinci_Code) but I am stuck on 'number/code' part used just before book name.
Moreover, names of some books are not capital and "-" is used instead of "." for some books which means there is no uniform way. I don't want to use API.

Example urls:

www.goodreads.com/book/show/968.The_Da_Vinci_Code

www.goodreads.com/book/show/7844725-elixir

So, I want to know a way of getting "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7844725-elixir"
after entering elixir? 
Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: where? what language? what runtime?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, C#, execution time...

Comment: please clarify further. what kind of code - winforms, console app - where do you want to the get url from?

Comment: ok now what window do you want to get the url from?

Comment: Code means the number used just before name of book

Comment: I dont understand. By window what do you mean?

Comment: you want to enter some substring and get goodreads.com's internal URL? If hey have no API for this you cannot do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the URL format (i.e. what components; id, name etc...) mean what in the URL and where to source them from.

In your example.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7844725-elixir

It would seem the part of the URL up as far as `/show/` is standardised, followed by GoodReads internal book Id. In fact a quick test, browsing to

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7844725

shows that the book name isn't even required. Do you have access to an API or Search on GoodReads in order to figure out what they're `book Id`s are ?

Have a look at their API if you haven't already. They have a bunch of search functions there which might get you what you need. i.e.

https://www.goodreads.com/api#book.title